# Cannot find module в TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Работаю в VSCode. Появилась такая проблемма. Он мне подсвечивает что

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'src./...'
```

При этом все работает, никаких проблем(кроме этой). В чем проблемма?

Comment: путь не валидный

Comment: проблемма в том, что он все находит. Ведь если ли бы путь не был валидным то он бы выкинул ошибку при кампиляции. Но у меня все пашет.

Answer (score 0):

Если сборка проекта идет с помощью команды `ng serve` то прощаются многие ошибки или неточности.
Можно попробовать сбилдить проект с помощью команды `ng build --prod` - причина будет более очевидная.